# Pyqt4 Qpixmap not working on Debian Beagleone Black image

Tags: python, pyqt4, qpixmap

I am trying a couple of sample programs that are not working in the last image of Debian for BBB. They work in a regular Xubuntu 13.10 distribution ad on windows but I have not been able to identify why Qpixmap is not working on this image. The regular widgets work Ok but the Qpixmap is not showing the image. The pyqt version installed is the 4.9.

One of the examples that I am using is the following.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

    class Imagen(QtGui.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):
            super(Example, self).__init__()

            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):      

            hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("test.png")

            lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

            hbox.addWidget(lbl)
            self.setLayout(hbox)

            self.move(300, 200)
            self.setWindowTitle('Test')
            self.show()        

    def main():

        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Imagen()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your png and python files are in the same directory add the following code:

Import os.path

```
import os.path as osp
```

add the following code to `initUI()`

```
...
path = osp.join(osp.direname(__file__), 'test.png')
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(path)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are relative to the *current* directory, which is not necessarily the same as the directory the script itself is in. So either use an absolute pathname, or cd to the directory the image file is in before running the script.

However, if you're interested in solving this general issue *properly*, the best approach is to learn how to use the [Qt Resource System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html) and the [pyrcc tool](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html). This allows you to embed icons (or any files you like) directly in your application, and thus completely side-steps any potential problems with locating files.